# How to create a custom JMenuBar?

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent, jmenubar

I want to create a custom menu bar class that i can add close and minimize buttons to. I want to extend the JMenuBar class but I don't know which methods to override or how to override them. I tried checking the java docs but that only tells you what a method does, not how it works. Can someone please help?

Comment: You can always check the source code.

Comment: Thanks, i searched for how to get that but for some stupid reason i didn't use the search term "source code".

Comment: It's often also available on your disk with your Java JDK download, something like source.zip.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can extend JMenuBar to create your own one. In order to have some custom menu buttons, you should ensure

1. Create a constructor with an ActionListener parameter

   public MyMenuBarClass(ActionListener p_objAl) {
      super();
      this.objal = p_objAl;
      initComponents();
   }
2. When you initial the menu buttons, you should add the ActionListener object into the added JMenuItem such as

   JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("menu 1");
   this.add(menu1); 
   JMenuItem menuitem1_1 = new JMenuItem("menu item 1.1");
   menuitem1_1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F10);
   menuitem1_1.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, 0));
   menuitem1_1.setActionCommand("command1_1");
   menuitem1_1.addActionListener(this.objal);
   menu1.add(menuitem1_1);
3. Implement the ActionListener object to handle the command such as command1_1 in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i modified the JMenuBar class to except all JComponents instead of just menu's.

```
public class CustomMenuBar extends JMenuBar{
    public JComponent addComponent(JComponent c) {
        super.add(c);
        return c;
    }
}
```